# Defining a custom cost function

Tags: keras-layer

I am looking for a deep learning implementation framework where I could define a custom cost function. By custom cost function I mean a cost function that is like:

> Cost = {one of general reconstruction cost} + lambda*|| w_l -
>   f(w_l)||_2

where `w_l` is the weight matrix in a specific layer.

Is this possible in Keras and can any one give me an example for this?

Thanks.